# Stackdriver logging misses log entries

Tags: python-3.x, logging, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

Our team uses python to log some user access activities.

We created both local logging and google cloud logging (Stackdriver) to capture the exceptions.

[Local log shows 5 entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hehZo.png)

[Our team's Stackdriver log shows 2 entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gdbu.png)

I also tested with my own google cloud stackdriver log. It shows 5 tries.

Here is the code:

```
local_logger = local_logging.getLogger(__name__)
local_logger.setLevel(local_logging.INFO)

handler = local_logging.FileHandler('Azure-user-access-audit-log.log')
handler.setLevel(local_logging.CRITICAL)


local_logging.Formatter.converter = time.gmtime
formatter = local_logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

local_logger.addHandler(handler)

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]  = "my-credential.json"
logging_client = cloud_logging.Client()
log_name = 'Azure-user-access-audit-log'
cloud_logger = logging_client.logger(log_name)

............

   if item['subcriptionType'] == 'Hacker':
        user_log = str(item['cloudName'] + " - " + item['tenantId'] + " | " +
            item['subcriptionType'] + " " + item['principalName'] + " has access to " + item['subscriptionName'] + " as "
            + item['roleDefinitionName'])
        local_logger.critical(user_log)

        # The data to log to Google Cloud
        google_log_message = item['subcriptionType'] + " " + item['principalName'] + " has access to " + item['subscriptionName'] + " as " + item['roleDefinitionName']
        google_log_severity = 'CRITICAL'
        google_log_insert_id = item['cloudName'] + " - " + item['tenantId']
        print(google_log_message)
        print(google_log_severity)
        print(google_log_insert_id)

        # Writes the log entry
        # cloud_logger.log_text(str(google_log_message), severity = str(google_log_severity), insert_id = str(google_log_insert_id))
        #             # cloud_logger.log_struct({
        #             #     'subcriptionType': item['subcriptionType'],
        #             #     'principalName': item['principalName'],
        #             #     'subscriptionName': item['subscriptionName']
        #             # }, severity = str(google_log_severity), insert_id = str(google_log_insert_id))
        cloud_logger.log_text(str(google_log_message))
```

If i added the commented-out piece of code for severity and insert-id, nothing would go through. I'm pretty sure that syntax was good.

Please help me out.
Thank y'all so much

Answer (score 3):

You are using `insertId` incorrectly. The Stackdriver Logging API [considers all log entries in the same project, with the same timestamp, and with the same insertId to be duplicates which can be removed](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#FIELDS.insert_id). All of your `insertId` values seem to be the same. The only reason you're seeing two entries in Stackdriver Logging and not one is that the two entries that do make it through have different timestamps.

You can just omit the `insertId` field. The API will set one automatically.